# strange folder in /tmp with name ssh-*

Tags: ssh, security, directory

while i do `ls` to the /tmp i found these files 
what is the meaing of the ssh folder i found

```
/tmp$ ls 
config-err-pBxjic
e5a28b00f2378661cc615788a1fef225-{87A94AB0-E370-4cde-98D3-ACC110C5967D}
gnome-software-TQ809Y
ssh-Rony2Zd8gQ6O
systemd-private-a789ca0968fb4855b28539acfbf9babe-colord.service-UCNgBR
systemd-private-a789ca0968fb4855b28539acfbf9babe-fwupd.service-4Xkw4W
systemd-private-a789ca0968fb4855b28539acfbf9babe-rtkit-daemon.service-KmLgj9
systemd-private-a789ca0968fb4855b28539acfbf9babe-systemd-resolved.service-F55I3N
systemd-private-a789ca0968fb4855b28539acfbf9babe-systemd-timesyncd.service-W5W5Kx
unity_support_test.0

/tmp$ cd ssh-Rony2Zd8gQ6O/
/tmp/ssh-Rony2Zd8gQ6O$ ls 
agent.1616
/tmp/ssh-Rony2Zd8gQ6O$ cat agent.1616 
cat: agent.1616: No such device or address
```

so what is the meaning of the existence of this folder and it's content

Comment: Did you use ssh lately? I have a similar folder here containing a symbolic link `agent.1909=`

Comment: no i didn't use SSH at all from this machine

Comment: O.k. check the output of `systemctl --state running | grep ssh`

Comment: I'd run `ls -aFl`.  That will show whether or not agent.116 is a special file.

Answer (score 13):

The folder contains sockets used by programs to communicate with [ssh-agent](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ssh-agent.1.html):

From the man page:

```
$TMPDIR/ssh-XXXXXXXXXX/agent.< ppid >
    UNIX-domain sockets used to contain the connection to the
    authentication agent.  These sockets should only be readable by
    the owner.  The sockets should get automatically removed when the
    agent exits.
```

Comment: so you mean it's normal ?

Answer (score 1):

[Florian's answer is correct](https://askubuntu.com/a/979915/1210606). However, if you find a lot of them building up, you can put this file in your $HOME/.bash_logout file:

```
[ -n "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ] &&
    ps -p "${SSH_AGENT_PID}" >/dev/null 2>&1 | grep ssh-agent &&
    kill "${SSH_AGENT_PID}"
```

I'm not sure if they remain due to a bug, or if that's how ssh-agent is designed. But on some of our systems we see old ssh-agent processes left running and those files left under /tmp. Killing the agent process should remove the /tmp/ssh-whatever directory and files, but if it doesn't on your system, you could add a line to check and remove it based on $SSH_AUTH_SOCK.